# How to update the response Content-Type after Servlet processing is done using ServeletFilter

Tags: java, servlets

I tried to change the ServletResponse Content-Type using ServletFilter. But, the servelet (in my content, AxisServlet) updates that Content-Type when chain.doFilter() calls. But other Response Headers are correctly updated.

I tried setting response headers after doFilter is called. At that time no response header was updated.

Does anyone know a way to update the Content-Type of the ServletResponse after Servelt is completed?

**Code :**

```
public class HeaderFilter implements Filter {

    private HashMap<String,String> rsCustomHeaders = new HashMap<String,String>();

    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {

        Enumeration<String> initParameterNames = config.getInitParameterNames();

        while (initParameterNames.hasMoreElements()) {

            String initParameterName = initParameterNames.nextElement();

            rsCustomHeaders.put(initParameterName, config.getInitParameter(initParameterName));

        }

        System.out.println("init().rsCustomHeaders : " + rsCustomHeaders);
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> rsCustomHeaderEntry : rsCustomHeaders.entrySet()) {
            httpServletResponse.addHeader(rsCustomHeaderEntry.getKey(), rsCustomHeaderEntry.getValue());
        }

        System.out.println("doFilter().encoding :Set Response Headers Done");

        chain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);

        System.out.println("doFilter().HeaderFilter is Done!!!");


    }

    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("destroy(). : Destroy is called!");
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>HeaderFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>filters.HeaderFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>content-type</param-name>
        <param-value>application/xml; charset=utf-8</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>Content_type</param-name>
        <param-value>text/xml; charset=utf-8</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>rq_content-type</param-name>
        <param-value>text/xml; charset=utf-8</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>Header-X</param-name>
        <param-value>Value-X</param-value>
      </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>HeaderFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/GradeThreeMath</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Did the rsCustomHeaders has loaded with values after init() ?

Comment: Also, are there any exception in server logs during startup & during processing ?

Comment: Yes values has been loaded correctly and there's no exceptions. And Resonse Headers other than content-type (eg : Header-X, Content_type ) has been successfully updated.

Comment: Add the code for AxisServlet  code ?

Comment: I like tp have it as the last option javaguy. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set content type on the original `response`.
Use [HttpServletResponseWrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponseWrapper.html) with overridden `setContentType` to wrap `response` that is passed to `child.doFilter`. Overridden `setContentType` should just ignore any attempts to change content type.

The code snippet:

```
// Setting content type
httpServletResponse.setContentType("you-content-type");
chain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, new HttpServletResponseWrapper(httpServletResponse) {
    @Override
    public void setContentType(final String type) {
        // Ignore any further attempts to change content type
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you kgeorgly. Let me try that!

Comment: kgeorgiy, one small thing. In my case, I want to send a space within the content type (eg : text/xml;charset=utf-8). Now content type is updated without a space. Do you have any idea around this?

Comment: Technically, the space is optional and does not affect content-type meaning. So, servlet container is free to strip it out, and no client, complying to specification should be affected. However, if you trying to work-around buggy client, you may try to use `response.setHeader` to provide exact `Content-Type` you want.

Comment: Ok kgeorgiy. I got your point. But I'm dealing with a kind of buggy client that requires this. And actually I'm already doing it in addition to setting the Content-Type. Anyway, I'll try it out further. Many thanx again!

Comment: I got it kgeorgy, When I send it like below it works. text/xml;&#8194;charset=utf-8

Comment: Wow! I think this against a standard, but I like an approach very much.